# SymPy: no effect of doit on a product of exponentials

Tags: product, sympy, exponential, doit

I am trying to get an exponential of a sum from the product of exponentials using SymPy.  It seems to work for any base, but *e* (Euler number).

Example of code with a generic base for the exponential:

```
from sympy import symbols, Function
from sympy import Product, E, pi, exp
i,n,base=symbols('i n base')
f=Function('f')
P=Product(base**f(i),(i,1,n))
P.doit()
```

P is the following expression:

[image]

and after applying doit(), it becames:

[image]

This code works for any base. I tested it with a number (eg.3.0), a variable (eg. *x*,*base*) or a constant defined in SymPy (eg. *pi*).
Just when base=euler number, the doit() does not work.

```
P=Product(E**f(i),(i,1,n))
P.doit()
```

or

```
P=Product(exp(f(i)),(i,1,n))
P.doit()
```

the result is still:

[image]
and not

[image]

A work around could be to subs *e* with a variable like *base* and to make the opposite substitution at the end.

But is there any better solution?

Versions: python 3.7.4, SymPy 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this works for the other cases but not exp because `E**x` is an instance of the class `exp` rather than `Pow`. Probably the sympy code can be made consistent by checking for both classes.

You can use rewrite to convert between Products and Sums using exp and log:

```
In [47]: P = Product(E**f(i), (i, 1, n))                                                                                                                      

In [48]: P                                                                                                                                                    
Out[48]: 
  n         
─┬──┬─      
 │  │   f(i)
 │  │  ℯ    
 │  │       
i = 1       

In [49]: P.rewrite(Sum)                                                                                                                                       
Out[49]: 
   n       
  ___      
  ╲        
   ╲       
   ╱   f(i)
  ╱        
  ‾‾‾      
 i = 1     
ℯ
```